# Changing quarterly data into hourly data

Tags: r, converters, aggregate

I have data as below. It is from 01.01.2015~31.12.2015.
The data is in quarterly base. But I want to add, for example, like 0:00, 0:15, 0:30, 0:45 together to make a hour data. How can I make this into hourly data?

Thank you in advance.

```
  Date      Hour Day-ahead Total Load Forecast [MW] - Germany (DE)
01.01.2015  0:00    42955
01.01.2015  0:15    42412
01.01.2015  0:30    41901
01.01.2015  0:45    41355
01.01.2015  1:00    40710
01.01.2015  1:15    40204
01.01.2015  1:30    39640
01.01.2015  1:45    39324
01.01.2015  2:00    39002
01.01.2015  2:15    38869
01.01.2015  2:30    38783
01.01.2015  2:45    38598
01.01.2015  3:00    38626
01.01.2015  3:15    38459
01.01.2015  3:30    38414
...


   > dput(head(new3))
structure(list(Date = structure(c(16436, 16436, 16436, 16436, 
16436, 16436), class = "Date"), Hour = c("0:00", "0:15", "0:30", 
"0:45", "1:00", "1:15"), Dayahead = c("42955", "42412", "41901", 
"41355", "40710", "40204"), Actual = c(42425L, 42021L, 42068L, 
41874L, 41230L, 40810L), Difference = c("530", "391", "-167", 
"-519", "-520", "-606")), .Names = c("Date", "Hour", "Dayahead", 
"Actual", "Difference"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 5):

I've created a small data set for example.

```
df <- read.csv(text = "Date,Hour,Val
2013-06-03,06:01,0
2013-06-03,12:08,-1
2013-06-03,12:48,3.3
2013-06-03,13:58,2
2013-06-03,13:01,12
2013-06-03,13:08,3
2013-06-03,14:48,4
2013-06-03,14:58,8
2013-06-03,15:01,9.2
2013-06-03,15:08,12.3
2013-06-03,16:48,0
2013-06-03,19:58,-10", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

With `group_by` and `summarize` from `dplyr` and `floor_date` from `lubridate` this can be done:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  group_by(Hours=floor_date(ymd_hm(paste(Date, Hour)), "1 hour")) %>%
  summarize(Val=sum(Val))

# # A tibble: 7 x 2
#   Hours                  Val
#   <dttm>               <dbl>
# 1 2013-03-06 06:00:00   0   
# 2 2013-03-06 12:00:00   2.30
# 3 2013-03-06 13:00:00  17.0 
# 4 2013-03-06 14:00:00  12.0 
# 5 2013-03-06 15:00:00  21.5 
# 6 2013-03-06 16:00:00   0   
# 7 2013-03-06 19:00:00 -10.0
```

Comment: Hello! I tried this but I am failing. I guess it is because my data for Hour and Val are in character. Should I change them to numeric to work it out?

Comment: @junmouse It will work with character, I think in your data set they are factors, so you need to drop factor from them, either with `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` for `read.csv` or manually.

Comment: I have character value as I also added stringsasfactors=F. I pasted your syntax and adjusted only the Val part, and it shows me `'# A tibble: 1 x 2
   Hours Actual
  <dttm>  <int>
1     NA     NA
Warning message:
All formats failed to parse. No formats found.'` I do not know what to do here .. hmm

Comment: @junmouse Can you `dput(head(...))` your data set to the question.

Comment: I have put it on my post. I just updated since I found something wrong. Please ignore actual and difference.

Comment: @junmouse OK, replace the `dmy_hm` in the call to `ymd_hm`. I assumed you have `Date` formatted as string, presented in post and therefore used conversion to datetime in that format.

Answer (score 3):

lets say your data frame is called df

```
> head(df)
        Date        Hour Forecast
1 01.01.2015 12:00:00 AM    42955
2 01.01.2015 12:15:00 AM    42412
3 01.01.2015 12:30:00 AM    41901
4 01.01.2015 12:45:00 AM    41355
5 01.01.2015 01:00:00 AM    40710
6 01.01.2015 01:15:00 AM    40204
```

you can aggregate your forecast to hourly basis by the following code

```
library(lubridate)
df$DateTime=paste(df$Date,df$Hour,sep=" ")%>%dmy_hms%>%floor_date(unit="hour")
result<-ddply(df,.(DateTime),summarize,x=sum(Forecast))
> result
             DateTime      x
1 2015-01-01 00:00:00 168623
2 2015-01-01 01:00:00 159878
3 2015-01-01 02:00:00 155252
4 2015-01-01 03:00:00 115499
```

variable x has the sum of forecasts for every hour. Timestamp 00:00:00 aggregates times 00:00, 00:15, 00:30, 00:45.